# TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, selenium, web-crawler

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv

la = open('loginscruz.csv', 'r')
listaluno = csv.reader(la,delimiter=';')

for alunos in listaluno[1:]:

    num = 1

    aluno = str(alunos[3])

    if (aluno != ''):
        print (aluno + " batata")
```

The error is in the line  `for alunos in listaluno[1:]:`

I'm pretty new on Python so im asking your help guys

Comment: `listaluno` is not a list. You cannot slice it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misunderstanding is that `listaluno` is not actually a list.  It is a *generator* that returns the next row *upon request*.  That means that you can't subscript it with `[1:]` because those rows *have not yet been parsed* by the CSV library -- they don't exist yet!  You can alter your code in a couple of ways.  Consider:

```
# Using the `list()` function will iterate through the generator and
# return the items as a list.  In effect, it "converts" the generator
# to a list.

la = open('loginscruz.csv', 'r')
listaluno = list(csv.reader(la,delimiter=';'))
```

The more Pythonic solution might ignore the first item by skipping it.

```
la = open('loginscruz.csv', 'r')
listaluno = list(csv.reader(la,delimiter=';'))

next(listaluno)
for alunos in listaluno:
  ...
```

Or perhaps

```
la = open('loginscruz.csv', 'r')
listaluno = list(csv.reader(la,delimiter=';'))

for lineno, alunos in enumerate(listaluno):
  if not lineno:
    # enumerate counts from 0 by default, so on first iteration,
    # lineno == 0, which is falsey
    continue

  ...
```

Finally, an argument why you should avoid the `list()` approach: Consider if your CSV file is absolutely huge, like terabytes or more.  If you were to convert it to a list as with the first approach, then you would run out of memory.  The generator solution solves this by only parsing each row as it's needed.  Further, perhaps you don't *need* every row, and your program or loop can quit early.  Saved effort by not preloading all the information that might not even get utilized.  This concept is generally known as *lazy evaluation*.

Answer (score 0):

As @juanpa.arrivillaga correctly suggested, `listaluno` is not a list. It is an iterator. You should either convert it to a list and then slice:

```
for alunos in list(listaluno)[1:]:
    do_stuff()
```

or simply skip the first iteration:

```
next(listaluno)
for alunos in listaluno:
    do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the itertools library, islice function

```
import csv
from itertools import islice

la = open('loginscruz.csv', 'r')
listaluno = iter(csv.reader(la,delimiter=';'))

    for listaluno in islice(listaluno ,1,None):
              num = 1

              aluno = str(listaluno[3])

              if (aluno != ''):
              print (f'{aluno} batata')
```

I don't know what your using nums = 1 for but if it just for numbering purpose, you can also use enumerate function for the same

```
import csv
from itertools import islice
```

la = open('loginscruz.csv', 'r')
listaluno = iter(csv.reader(la,delimiter=';'))

for count, listaluno in enumerate(islice(listaluno,1,None), start = 1):
      aluno = str(listaluno[3])

`if (aluno != ''):
    print (f'{count} {aluno} batata')`